# less function to fade pre-determined div background

Tags: .net, css, less, dotless

### Background / Goal

I some divs. On each of these divs, I'd like to place two different classes (each of which have different logical meanings within my app).

I would like one class to represent a level, which would translate into the color of the div. I would like another class to represent distance, and control a fade level of whatever background is applied.

So I would like the div to look like:

```
<div class="element level-beginner distance-long">
```

And would like that to translate into, say, a green background that is faded.

I know a little bit about LESS (but only a little bit), and don't this seems like a case where nested styles would help (because it doesn't deal with a child element but rather whether a certain class has already been applied).

Essentially, **I'd like to control the color and the opacity/fade as CSS classes that are independent of each other**.

### Question

- Is there a way to utilize less so that a class will control the alpha/fade of the background of a div element without having to specify the color as well?

Comment: Personally, I would add a semantic class name and then just use a mixin with a few arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LESS color opacity functions (fadein, fadeout, fade) require a color as their first argument.  LESS has no idea how you're going to combine your classes, so it doesn't know where to get the color from.

There is an `opacity` property in CSS, but it adjusts the transparency of the entire element (including the text).

Your only real option is to write out selectors for each combination you're planning to use or have a mixin that will generate them for you:

```
.themeMatrix(@color) {
    &.styleA {
        background: fade(@color, 50%);
    }

    &.styleB {
        background: fade(@color, 20%);
    }

    &.styleC {
        border: 1px solid @color;
    }
}

.colorA {
    .themeMatrix(white);
}

.colorB {
    .themeMatrix(green);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, both for confirming that what I wanted to do wasn't inherently possible, and for the great example you provided to go with it. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

With just HTML, CSS and LESS, there is no way for one class applied to an element to "know" what another class's background color is in order to fade it out. It's just not possible.

However, you can still get a similar effect that allows you to chain classes to create new effects.

The basic, plain CSS way to write this would be like this:

```
.fire {
  background: rgb(255,0,0)
}
.fire.level-beginner {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.5)
}
.fire.level-pro {
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.25)
}
```

With this CSS, if an element has the class `.fire` *and* `.level-beginner`, it gets the faded out background.

Now, here is why preprocessors are cool: we can let mixins take care of making the nested classes so adding a new color (for example `.water` with `blue`) with all the nested sub-options is a one line affair:

**LESS:**

```
.colorfade(@fade) {
  background: fadeout(@color, @fade);
}

.colorfind (@color) {
  background: @color;
  &.level-beginner {
    .colorfade(50%)
  }
  &.level-pro {
    .colorfade(25%)
  }
}

.fire {
  .colorfind(red);
}

.water {
  .colorfind(blue);
}

.earth {
  .colorfind(green);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="fire level-beginner"></div>
<div class="water level-pro"></div>
<div class="earth level-beginner"></div>
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/kheAi)